# Reporte en CodeIgniter, problemas Foreach(Alinear td con th)

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Necesito generar la tabla que muestro en la imagen con los encabezados que están arriba.

Tengo problemas al momento de querer acomodar las operaciones de los empleados de acuerdo a los encabezados. Arregle mi problema con los espacios, el problema es que no se acomodan de acuerdo a la operación correspondiente, ¿pueden ayudarme por favor?

Es en esta parte donde realizo el llenado de la tabla en la sección de colores:

```php
if(!empty($obtenOperacion)) {
    foreach($obtenOperacion as $fi) { 
        if(!empty($consulta) ) {
            foreach($consulta as $fil) {
                if($fila->cveEmpleado==$fil->cveEmpleado AND $fi->operacion==$fil->operacion AND isset($fil->operacion)){ 
                    echo "<td class='$fil->color'<h4> $fil->operacion</h4> X</td>";
                }
                elseif ($fila->cveEmpleado!=$fil->cveEmpleado AND $fi->operacion==$fil->operacion) {
                    echo "<td>N/A</td>";
                }#cierra else
            }#Cierra consulta 
        }#Cierra if que compara operación
    }#Cierra foreach fi 
}#Cierra if de obtenOperacion
```

Aquí los estilos

```
.azul{
color: #FFFFFF;
background-color: #4B42EC;
font-weight: bold;
}

.azul-marino{
color: #FFFFFF;
background-color: #162D82;
font-weight: bold;
}

.blanco{
color: #000000;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
font-weight: bold;
}

.verde{
color: #FFFFFF;
background-color: #15981D;
font-weight: bold;
}

.amarillo{
color: #000000;
background-color: #F1DB16;
font-weight: bold;
}

.gris{
color: #FFFFFF;
background-color: #6B6B6B;
font-weight: bold;
}

.Marrón{
color: #FFFFFF;
background-color: #663217;
font-weight: bold;
}

.naranja{
color: #FFFFFF;
background-color: #F8751E;
font-weight: bold;
}

.rosa{
color: #000000;
background-color: #F560FA;
font-weight: bold;
}

.morado{
color: #FFFFFF;
background-color: #913EF7;
font-weight: bold;
}

.negro{
color: #FFFFFF;
background-color: #000000;
font-weight: bold;
}

.rojo{
color: #FFFFFF;
background-color: #DC1717;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

Aquí donde realizo las consultas

```
function consulta($idBloque, $fecha1, $fecha2) {

  $this->db->select("eo.cveEmpleado, eo.idOperacion, o.operacion, b.bloque, c.color, DATEDIFF( NOW( ) , e.fechaIngreso ) diferencia, eo.idEstatus,est.estatus,eo.fechaCertifica");
  $this->db->from('empleado e, estatus est,  color c, bloque b, emp_opera eo, operacion o');
  $this->db->where('eo.idOperacion = o.idOperacion AND est.idEstatus = eo.idEstatus  AND b.idBloque = o.idBloque AND o.idColor = c.idColor AND e.cveEmpleado= eo.cveEmpleado '); 
  $this->db->where('b.idBloque' , $idBloque);
  $this->db->where("eo.fechaCertifica >='$fecha1'");
  $this->db->where("eo.fechaCertifica <='$fecha2'");
  $this->db->group_by('o.operacion,o.idOperacion, eo.cveEmpleado');
  $bloque = $this->db->get();
  return $bloque->result();
}
function obtenOperacion($idBloque) {

  $this->db->select('o.idOperacion,o.operacion,o.idBloque,b.bloque, b.idArea, a.area, c.color, o.idColor');
  $this->db->from('operacion o, area a, color c, emp_opera eo, bloque b');
  $this->db->where('o.idBloque = b.idBloque and b.idArea = a.idArea and o.idColor=c.idColor');
  $this->db->where('o.idBloque', $idBloque);
  $this->db->group_by('o.idOperacion');
  $operacion = $this->db->get();
  return $operacion->result();
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola!!! Este sitio es solo en español, así que por favor si hablas el idioma te pediría que solo dejes tu consulta en el idioma del sitio. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Vale muchas gracias :)

Comment: ¿me puedes ayudar?, por favor :)

Comment: Me encantaria, pero desconozco totalmente este lenguaje. Lo siento. Igual deberias dejar bien en claro a que quieres llegar, y cual es el error. Fijate q nunca dices que es lo que anda mal

Comment: Cierto, cierto gracias

Comment: De acuerdo, subiré mis estilos y edito la imagen para que se vea, muchas gracias  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He aquí la solución ami problema:
En el controlador debía de poner esto y filtrar la consulta por empleado y operación para consecuente imprimir un valor que se comparara de acuerdo a la operación que lanzaba, ya que anteriormente mandaba todos los datos de la consulta, y se repetían.

```
 <?php  
          if(!empty($obtenOperacion)) {
           foreach($obtenOperacion as $fi) { 
            $this->load->model('Reportes_model');
            $fil=$this->Reportes_model->consulta($fila->idBloque, $fecha1, $fecha2, $fila->cveEmpleado, $fi->idOperacion);
            if(!empty($fil))
            {

             foreach($fil as $fil) 
             {

               if($fi->idOperacion==$fil->idOperacion)
               { 

                echo "<td class='$fil->color'><h4> $fil->operacion</h4> X</td>";        
                }#cierra else                
           }#Cierra consulta 
         }
         else
         {

          echo "<td>N/A</td>";
          }#Cierra if que compara operación
        }#Cierra foreach fi 
    }#Cierra if de obtenOperacion 
} #cierre de foreach fila
} #Cierre if consulta ?>
```